# Will I be punished if I mark a question as duplicate which answers half the question?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, duplicate-questions

I just now marked this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19933256/remove-in-arraylist-java) as a duplicate of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714233/remove-item-from-arraylist) which is 
half right. 50% of the OP's question's answer is described in the duplicate question.

Is it right to do so? If not will be banned from asking questions or answering anything (punishment).

Comment: +1 Interesting question, I did this about a week ago and the OP went crazy at me, and was rather rude but I felt as though I did the right thing.

Comment: @JMK Thanks for considering it as a good question

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, you won't be punished. Far from it, you are trying to keep the site clean and help the OP by pointing to another post that can help, which is great!

You have a *vote* to mark a question as a duplicate. Others will have to agree and vote the same way before a question is marked as as such. They may also vote to close the question for other reasons.

If they don't agree with you, they could perhaps state so in the comments, but you will not lose reputation or otherwise get in bother. Your ability to post is certainly not going to be affected.

Of course, if you go around voting to close random questions willy-nilly and continue to do so even when asked to stop, then a moderator *may* step in and put your account on temporary suspension, but that'd be an extreme case.

Comment: will I get any kind of punishment if I get lots of downvotes on answers.I know if i get downvotes on question then i will be banned from asking question

Comment: @rocking: That is entirely separate from voting to close. If someone were to be upset over you voting to close a question and seek you out to downvote your posts, then that'd be serial voting, not allowed, and likely to be reverted.

Comment: If my answers gets downvotes then will i get any punishement?

Comment: If too many of your answers get downvoted and / or you delete too many of your answers, then you can risk a posting ban. But that is an entirely separate issue from voting-to-close a question as a duplicate.

Comment: Other than that, downvotes cost you 2 points reputation, that can be seen as a punishment.

Comment: I just now answered another question and it got 3 downvotes.So i deleted that answer.Yesterday also I got downvotes to an answer so again i deleted.So i was wondering if this will be a problem

Comment: See [What can I do when getting “We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account”?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/86997); I wouldn't worry too much, though.

Answer (score 1):

The best option in that case is probably to not mark the question as a duplicate (because "close only counts in Horseshoes and hand grenades..."), but rather to post a link to the "duplicate" and fill in the blanks for the asker.  Or at least tell them that the link contains part of the answer they seek.

Mistakingly flagging something won't get you banned or punished, unless at some point it's deemed that you're doing so blatantly for no reason.  In your case, I wouldn't sweat it.

Answer (score 0):

**No, you won't be punished or banned** from asking question on any sites. They will remove the question only if some more persons vote along with you for the same reasons.